# Why Firestore Security Rules auth token name is always null?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I try to compare the request.auth.token.name with the document name in the Firestore Security Rules, to give only the user access to his specific document. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work out. I tried a bit and it seems that the name is null. But why? Can anybody relate or have an answer for this?

The problem:

```
W/Firestore(30226): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at users/johndoe: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

The security rule:

```
match /users/{username} {
  allow create: if true;
  allow update: if request.auth.token.name == username;
  allow read: if true;
```

The client code (written in Dart for Flutter):

```
@override
  Future<void> uploadProfileData(ProfileSetupDataModel data) async {
    // Checks if username is already in use and creates a document (works perfectly)
    final userDocReference = await _createDocIfUsernameAvailable(data.username);
    // Here the username is saved in the display name of the FirebaseUser
    await _saveUsernameInAuthUser(data.username);
    // Write all the other information into the user document
    await _fillProfileInformation(userDocReference, data); // -> here the problem occurs
  }


Future<void> _saveUsernameInAuthUser(String username) async {
    try {
      final user = await auth.currentUser();
      final profileUpdate = UserUpdateInfo();
      profileUpdate.displayName = username;
      await user.updateProfile(profileUpdate);
    } catch (e) {
      throw GeneralAuthException();
    }
  }


Future<void> _fillProfileInformation(
      DocumentReference userDocReference, ProfileSetupDataModel data) async {
    try {
      await userDocReference.setData(
        {
          FirestoreUserKeys.birthday: data.birthday,
          FirestoreUserKeys.sex: data.sex,
          FirestoreUserKeys.country: data.country,
          FirestoreUserKeys.storiesCount: 0,
          FirestoreUserKeys.subscribersCount: 0,
          FirestoreUserKeys.subscriptionsCount: 0,
          FirestoreUserKeys.totalLikes: 0,
        },
        merge: true,
      );
    } on PlatformException {
      throw GeneralCloudFirestoreException();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use request.resource.id instead of username.

Comment: I suggest not using `request.auth.token.name` at all.  You should instead use the UID of the user.  This is by far the most common approach, and it's what you see in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! You made me think about it and I'm now using a slightly different approach which works

Comment: Hey @Nico! Would you mind sharing the approach you took? I am facing a very similar issue.

Comment: @erwinleonardy It was a simple change I've made: I just added the UID to the documents as a separate field (because I am using the usernames as document ids). Hope it can help you somehow!

Comment: Thanks @Nico That was precisely what I did too! Appreciate it :) Have a nice day!